# PHP: Combine two variable to equal dollar amount for total price

Tags: php, variables

I recently took over some really old PHP scripts for a small store. The are calls made on the order form for getting the product price as well as the shipping price. That's all good. However, I need some help in combining the two values together into a total price.

Here's how the script currently works:

```
<ul>
    <li><b>{{cart['main_product']['productName']}}</b><strong class="pull-right text-primary">${{cart['main_product']['productPrice']}}</strong></li>
    <li><b>Sub Total</b><strong class="pull-right text-primary">${{cart['main_product']['productPrice'] ? cart['main_product']['productPrice'] : "0.00"}}</strong></li>
    <li><b>Shipping</b><strong class="pull-right text-primary">${{cart['main_product']['shippingPrice'] ? cart['main_product']['shippingPrice'] : "0.00"}}</strong></li>
    <li><b>Total</b><strong class="pull-right text-primary">${{cart['main_product']['productPrice']}} + ${{cart['main_product']['shippingPrice']}}</strong></li>
 </ul>
```

As you can see in that last LI, I have it where in the Total area I can display the value of the product + shipping price, but that's all. I can't figure out how to combine the two values together to get that total price. What would work?

UPDATE: I'm trying to add all this in a function but it's weird. I can get the initial values to display but not when they are added together. Here's my function in PHP:

```
$sum=0;
$selling_price="{{cart['main_product']['productPrice']}}"; // 6.95
$cost_price="{{cart['main_product']['shippingPrice']}}"; 2.00
$total_price=$selling_price+$cost_price;
echo "The value of product price is $selling_price \n";
echo "The value of shipping price is $cost_price \n";
echo "Total: $",$total_price;
```

And here's the end result from the three echo statements:

The value of product price is 6.95 The value of shipping price is 2.00 Total: $0

That should have added the two values, but didn't. Why?

Comment: That's not PHP code, it looks like some kind of template framework.

Comment: No, it’s all part of an overall PHP script.

Comment: But `${{ ... }}` is not PHP coding. You should add the tag for whatever is processing those fields.

Comment: What does `print_r($selling_price);` show? Also, what templating language are you using that has this `${{ ... }}` syntax?

Comment: @Barmar, so the values come from the index.php page which creates the variables this way for each product.

<a href="order.php" ng-click="updateCart('main_product',{'productName': '<?php echo $product; ?> <?php echo $bundle_3_description; ?>', 'productId':'', 'productPrice': '<?php echo $bundle_3_price; ?>', 'shippingPrice': '2.00' , 'productQty': '1'});">Buy Now</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which should create a single expression consisting of those two numbers added together:

```
<strong class="pull-right text-primary">${{1*cart['main_product']['productPrice'] + 1*cart['main_product']['shippingPrice']}}</strong>
```

The `1*` ensures the strings are converted to numbers before being added together.

Comment: Isn’t this what I already have in my example?

Comment: @AdamBell No, you have `${{cart['main_product']['productPrice']}} + ${{cart['main_product']['shippingPrice']}}` which if you read carefully is not the same.

Comment: You;re right and my apologies to you on that. I see the difference now.

It works. Sort of. Instead of the total displaying at let's say $6.95 it displays as $0.006.95 instead. So how do we get rid of the extra zeroes?

Comment: OK, I figured out what your function is doing. Instead of adding the two variables together, it's combining them. So let's say I had a product with a price of $5.00 and shipping was $1.00, the total should be $6.00. However, with your function, that would be displayed as $5001.00 which obviously turns it into a very expensive product.

So maybe the plus sign is not the right symbol to use here.

Comment: @AdamBell They're probably strings so you'll have to cast them to numbers first: `(float)cart['main_product']['productPrice'] + (float)cart['main_product']['shippingPrice']`

Comment: No, that just messed everything up. If I did add the double curly brackets to your code, I would get all the variables to show up as code. Not just the total. So the total would appear as ${{(float)cart['main_product']['productPrice'] + (float)cart['main_product']['shippingPrice']}}

If I eliminate the curlies, The other three values are back to normal but the code still appear in the total like I just mentioned. Just no curly brackets.

Comment: @AdamBell You will always need to surround the code with `${{ ... }}`. I was not suggesting you remove them. I was just showing what code inside would have to change. In any case, try: `${{floatval(cart['main_product']['productPrice']) + floatval(cart['main_product']['shippingPrice'])}}`.

Comment: I just updated my original question because I found a way to do this as a PHP based function using variables. Which kind of works but still doesn't seem to want to add the two values together.

Comment: that last example you sent just came up as blank. Not even a zero. I just added a comment about another method I'm trying, but it isn't working either.

Comment: Ok, one last guess: `${{1*cart['main_product']['productPrice'] + 1*cart['main_product']['shippingPrice']}}`

Comment: IT WORKED! You're the Christmas Miracle!

Comment: @AdamBell Great! I've updated my answer to show this new code.

Comment: So I just found a weird error. Seems depending upon either the productPrice or the shippingPrice, you get weird tabulations. For example if a product is 59.99 and the shipping is 10 bucks, the tabulation is 69.99000000000001 instead of 69.99.

Likewise, if the product is 59.95 and the shipping is 11.25, the tabulation is 75.2 instead of 75.20.

Comment: If your templating engine allows it, you can use PHP's `number_format()` function to format the number to two decimal places: `${{number_format(1*cart['main_product']['productPrice'] + 1*cart['main_product']['shippingPrice'],2)}}`.

Comment: Yea, I  thought about number_format but wasn't sure how to incorporate it. I think there's a money_format as well. Unfortunately, adding that code only made the tabulation disappear. So you just get '$' and nothing else.

Comment: @AdamBell My code doesn't add a '$' so I'm not sure where that would have come from. Also, `money_format()` is deprecated.

Comment: The $ is likely the first character (which isn't dynamic) so if it was just {{number_format(1*cart['main_product']['productPrice'] + 1*cart['main_product']['shippingPrice'],2)}}, then there would be no result at all. Just blank.

Comment: @AdamBell Without further information on the templating language your system uses to interpolate code in the double braces, it's difficult to determine how to resolve this.